# I need Logic(JAVA) to avoid duplicate Rows in the Excel Sheet while Updating in DB

Tags: java, sql-server, excel

I am using Apache POI for reading excel values and sometimes i am encountering duplicate rows in the excel sheet and that Row values also updated in the DB and i am getting the wrong Values for number of Rows Inserted in DB

So i need JAVA Logic for how to Identify duplicate Records in Excel Sheet and how to Remove that value?

Comment: how about using a java.util.TreeSet and putting each record into a Comparable ? that will ensure unique values, although that could be bad for the heap. an alternative I can think of is to maintain the uniqueness identifiers in a collection and checking for each record against it.

Comment: Yup.. It will work fine..  Tnx for that..

Answer (score 1):

The easy way is to add constraint on your DB to prevent duplicate rows from inserting.

Or you can keep the rows in memory(such as in a [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/)) to avoid duplicate rows, but this is not applicable when there are too many rows.

The third way is to sort Excel rows before reading, then read them row by row. In this way you need not to keep all of them in memory, since you can judge duplication by comparing every continued 2 rows only.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use a "Set" to store the row data OR before inserting, you can check in database if the row already exists.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using a POJO which you are creating from one row in the excel sheet and then inserting it into the database, you should implement `equals()` and `hashCode()` in that object. Then you add those object to a `Set`. Before adding a new object to the database you check if it is already in the `Set` (already added).